# Saving extended user model data from POST method API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I don't have any forms to get input from user only by using POSTMAN i have tested this.
I extend my default user model by OneToOneField

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

and i implemented below method

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile = Profile(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

so it creates a record for profile while any record gets inserted in user model.

For example If i have made any API call like localhost:8000/signup with POST method data like 
username: abc, password: passkey123, phone: 9876543210 it save username and password in user model respective profile model created with user reference failed to update my phone number field.

I don't have any forms to get datas. Below is my view that routed from /signup

```
@api_view(['post'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def signup(request):
    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    email = request.data.get('email')
    phone = request.data.get('phone')

    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password,
                                email=email)
    if not user:
        return Response({'message': 'Failed'}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({'message': 'success'})
```

Do i need to implement any special signal to pass the input data like phone and address to profile model or extra lines i have to add.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I don't have any forms" well that's clearly the problem you need to solve

Comment: I'm building the above for mobile app interaction so making this as a pure rest service

Comment: then replace the word form with serializer